# Shortcuts to came back to the previous position after go to the definition?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + left mouse click on a reference variable or class name used in another class, I can move forward to its definition. But I need to know how to move backward again using shortcut keys. I don't know what are the keys use for it.

Answer (score 1):

After you go to the definition of an object, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to go back to where you were.  You can see this if you hover over the back arrow button:

[image: back button]

You can change this setting as well.  It is called the `View.NavigateBackward` shortcut under Environment → Keyboard:

[image: shortcut]

Comment: Thank you, it is very valuable me to save my time.

Comment: @NaminSaranga if you found the answer helpful, be sure to accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left.

Comment: How to do that in visual studio code not in visual studio? (Alt + ←) is working for that, but any other shortcut is available?

Comment: @NaminSaranga that's a different question, but File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts.  Or, CTRL + K, CTRL + S